# Meaning of stake2votes function

Tags: staking, voting, unit-tests

`eosio_system_tester.hpp`:

```
 double stake2votes( asset stake ) {
    auto now = control->pending_block_time().time_since_epoch().count() / 1000000;
    return stake.get_amount() * pow(2, int64_t((now - (config::block_timestamp_epoch / 1000)) / (86400 * 7))/ double(52) ); // 52 week periods (i.e. ~years)
 }
```

How does this formula (relation of stake amount and time) make physical sense?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a test function that helps making sure the `stake2vote()` works as intended.

The `stake2vote()` function from[`contracts/eosio.system/voting.cpp`](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/905e7c85714aee4286fa180ce946f15ceb4ce73c/contracts/eosio.system/voting.cpp#L105-L109) is as follows:

```
double stake2vote( int64_t staked ) {
   double weight = int64_t( (now() - (block_timestamp::block_timestamp_epoch / 1000)) / (seconds_per_day * 7) )  / double( 52 );
   return double(staked) * std::pow( 2, weight );
}
```

In the code above, `weight` is the time elapsed (in years) from `block_timestamp::block_timestamp_epoch`, which [is year 2000](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/4da680bdfe1f68a11edb332252e015f4f533c443/libraries/chain/include/eosio/chain/config.hpp#L44). The `weight` variable in the code, therefore, increases linearly with time.

However, the return value multiplies the amount staked by `2^w`, making the value of a vote increase exponentially as time passes. In other words, the later you vote, the more weight your vote has. Note that `weight` increases every week as the number of weeks is casted to a `uint64_t` before dividing by number of weeks in a year.

Thus, the formula is as shown below:

[image: v=2^t x s]

where `v` is the "value" of your vote, `t` is the time elapsed since year 2000 and is measured in years and updated every week, and `s` is the amount of EOS you staked with. While old votes will keep their values, new votes will weigh more, implicitly decaying the relative weight of old votes.

The function you quoted is a helper function used in unit testing to verify that the `stake2vote()` function works as intended.